# Как лучше читать читать данные из DBF в C#

Tags: c#, dbf

Задача: пользователи раз в месяц грузят данные от поставщиков в базу.
Файлы приходят разных размеров. от 1 Кб до 500Мб.

Сейчас реализовано работа с файлами по принципу грузим в DataTable и потом пишем в БД.
Все хорошо пока пользователи, в количестве 50, не начинают делать это одновременно. На сервере IIS заканчивается память. 
Возможно загрузка файлов допускает утечку памяти. Пока не получается это выявить.

Есть идея уменьшить нагрузку на IIS, грузить сразу в БД.

Но как всегда есть "но".

Сейчас реализовано через FileStream читаем байты анализируем что прочитали и формируем datatable записывая каждую ячейку по отдельности. и потом через BulkCopy в БД

Если сравнивать производительность с использованием OleDbDataAdapter.Fill
То формирование DataTable Проигрывает в два раза медленее.

Если используем  SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(OleDbDataReader) то производительность по с равнению с имеющимися падает, на примере 250 Мб вместо 10 секунд получаем 15 секунд. но зато выигрываем по памяти.

Как всегда время является критичным...

может кто подскажет что можно со всем этим сделать.

пример с OleDbDataReader

```
using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection($"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={Path.GetDirectoryName(FileName)}; Extended Properties=dBASE IV;"))
{
    connection.Open();
    var name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(FileName);
    var schem2 = connection.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Columns, new object[] { null, null, name });
    List<String> Select = new List<String>();
    DataTable DT2 = new DataTable(Table);//Для того чтобы сгенерить скрипт для создания таблицы в базе
    foreach (DataRow c in schem2.Rows)
    {
        DT2.Columns.Add(c["COLUMN_NAME"].ToString(), oleDbToNetTypeConverter((int)c["DATA_TYPE"]));
        Select.Add(c["COLUMN_NAME"].ToString());
    }
    var cmd2 = CreateCommandClass.CreateCreateTableCommand(Table, DT2);
    DB.ExecNonQueryWithError(cmd2);
    OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand($"SELECT {String.Join(",", Select)} FROM {name}", connection);
    OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy =
        new SqlBulkCopy(UserInfoClass.GetUserInfo().ConnectASPDB))
    {
        bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = Table;
        bulkCopy.BulkCopyTimeout = 360; 
        try
        {
            bulkCopy.WriteToServer(reader);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            err.ErrorMessage = ex.Message;
            err.HasError = true;
        }
        finally
        {
            reader.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Как работает сейчас

```
using (FileStream FS = new FileStream(FileName, FileMode.Open))
            {
                ThrowErrorMessage = "";
                try
                {
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[4]; // Кол-во записей: 4 байтa, начиная с 5-го
                    FS.Position = 4;
                    FS.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    int RowsCount = buffer[0] + (buffer[1] * 0x100) + (buffer[2] * 0x10000) + (buffer[3] * 0x1000000); //количество строк

                    DT.MinimumCapacity = (RowsCount > 50000) ? 50000 : RowsCount;
                    buffer = new byte[2]; // Кол-во полей: 2 байтa, начиная с 9-го
                    FS.Position = 8;
                    FS.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    int FieldCount = (((buffer[0] + (buffer[1] * 0x100)) - 1) / 32) - 1; //количество полей, каждое описание поля длиной- длиной 32 байта
                    string[] FieldName = new string[FieldCount]; // Массив названий полей
                    string[] FieldType = new string[FieldCount]; // Массив типов полей
                    byte[] FieldSize = new byte[FieldCount]; // Массив размеров полей
                    byte[] FieldDigs = new byte[FieldCount]; // Массив размеров дробной части
                    buffer = new byte[32 * FieldCount]; // Описание полей: 32 байтa * кол-во, начиная с 33-го
                    FS.Position = 32;
                    FS.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    int FieldsLength = 0;
                    for (int i = 0; i < FieldCount; i++)
                    {
                        // Заголовки
                        string titler = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(buffer, i * 32, 10).TrimEnd((char)0x00);
                        string title2 = "";
                        int pos = 0;
                        while (pos < titler.Length && titler[pos] != '\0')
                        {
                            title2 += titler[pos++];
                        }
                        //переименовать, если колонка с таким нименованием уже есть
                        if (DT.Columns.Contains(title2))
                            title2 = title2 + "_" + (i + 1);
                        if (DT.Columns.Contains(title2))
                            title2 = title2 + "_" + (i + 1);
                        //
                        FieldName[i] = title2;
                        FieldType[i] = "" + (char)buffer[i * 32 + 11];
                        FieldSize[i] = buffer[i * 32 + 16];
                        FieldDigs[i] = buffer[i * 32 + 17];
                        FieldsLength = FieldsLength + FieldSize[i];
                        // Создаю колонки
                        switch (FieldType[i])
                        {
                            ///Определяем типы
                        }
                        if (FieldType[i] != "\0")
                        {
                            DT.Columns[FieldName[i]].ExtendedProperties["len"] = FieldSize[i];
                            DT.Columns[FieldName[i]].ExtendedProperties["declen"] = FieldDigs[i];
                        }
                    }

                    {
                        FS.ReadByte(); // Пропускаю стартовый байт элемента данных                   

                        System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo dfi = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US", false).DateTimeFormat;
                        System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo nfi = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US", false).NumberFormat;
                        buffer = new byte[FieldsLength];

                        int start = 0;
                        while (start == 0) // выбираем все нулы
                            start = FS.ReadByte(); // Пропускаю стартовый байт элемента данных                                                              

                        DT.BeginLoadData();
                        try
                        {
                            int FilePos;
                            if (RowsPortion != 0)
                            {
                                RowsCount = RowsPortion;
                                FilePos = (buffer.Length + 1) * RowsStart;//+1 делаем для того,чтобы учесть пропущенные стартовые байты элементов данных
                                FS.Position = FS.Position + FilePos + ((RowsStart != 0 && RowsPortion != 0) ? -1 : 0);
                            }

                            for (int j = 0; j < RowsCount; j++)//RowsPortion
                            {
                                if (j != 0 || (RowsStart != 0 && RowsPortion != 0))
                                    start = FS.ReadByte(); // Пропускаю стартовый байт элемента данных

                                DataRow R = DT.NewRow();
                                int Index = 0;

                                for (int i = 0; i < R.Table.Columns.Count; i++)
                                {
                                    string l = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(CodePage).GetString(buffer, Index, FieldSize[i]).TrimEnd((char)0x00, (char)0x20);//TrimEnd(new char[] { (char)0x00 }).TrimEnd(new char[] { (char)0x20 });
                                    Index = Index + FieldSize[i];
                                    try
                                    {
                                        if (l != "")
                                            switch (FieldType[i])
                                            {
                                                ///записываем значения в соответствии с типом
                                            }
                                        else
                                            R[i] = DBNull.Value;
                                    }
                                    catch { if (l.Contains("")) { } }
                                }
                                ///Добавляем в DataTable
                                DT.Rows.Add(R);
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            ThrowErrorMessage = RowsStart + "Ошибка при добавлении строки в таблицу (" + DT.Rows.Count + "/" + RowsCount + ")" + ex.Message;
                        }
                        finally
                        {
                            DT.EndLoadData();
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    ThrowErrorMessage = "Ошибка при создании таблицы:" + ex.Message;
                }
                finally
                {
                    FS.Close();
                }
            }
```

Comment: делайте отложенные задачи на загрузку данных пользователей, пользователь только отправляет сам файл, а ваш сервис уже в фоновом режиме делает загрузку данных из файла, при этом ваш веб-сервер не будет нагружен

Comment: Загрузка данных в базу это один из этапов. Для реализации отложенного необходимо переделать сложившийся тех процесс.

Просто так переделать не получится.
Файлы приходят в разных форматах xls,dbf,xml и разной структуры.
В частности с DBF сопоставление полей файла и БД происходит после записи в базу.
Зада написана кучу лет назад.. и работала пока с ПО работало порядка 20-30 человек по всем задачам.

Сейчас с ПО работают  порядка 1000 пользователей. и 50 из них портят работу всем остальным.

**Все таки пока задача стоит в переделки небольшого блока.**

Comment: почему нельзя выделить конкретно эту задачу в отдельный сервис загрузки? это освободит ваш веб-сайт

Comment: Можно..........